# Doubt about solution to Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right problem

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation, solution-verification

I am confused about a solution by Stanford's MATH113 class to a problem in Sheldon Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right, 3rd Ed.* I have seen solutions elsewhere (on Slader) that are very similar.

The question (3.A.11, pg 58) is below, where $\mathcal{L}(V, W)$ denotes the set of all linear maps from $V$ to $W$.

> Suppose $V$ is finite-dimensional. Prove that every linear map on a subspace of $V$ can be extended to a linear map on $V$. In other words, show that if $U$ is a subspace of $V$ and $S \in \mathcal{L}(U, W)$, then there exists $T \in \mathcal{L}(V, W)$ such that $Tu = Su$ for all $u \in U$.

Below is the solution from [Stanford's MATH113 class, Fall 2015](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Echurch/teaching/113-F15/). I was unable to find any of the Propositions or Definitions mentioned.

> *Proof*. Suppose $U$ is a subspace of $V$ and $S \in \mathcal{L}(U, W)$. Choose a basis $u_1, \ldots, u_m$ of $U$. Then $u_1, \ldots, u_m$ is a linearly independent list of vectors in $V$ and so can be extended to a basis $u_1, \ldots, u_m, v_1, \ldots, v_n$ of $V$ (by Proposition 2.33). Using Proposition 3.5, we know that there exists a unique linear map $T \in \mathcal{L}(V, W)$ such that
> \begin{align} 
>     Tu_i = Su_i \quad &\text{for all} \quad i \in \{1, 2, \ldots, m\} \\
>     Tv_j = 0 \quad &\text{for all} \quad j \in \{ 1, 2, \ldots, n \} .
> \end{align}
> Now we are going to prove $Tu = Su$ for all $u \in U$. For any $u \in U$ $u$ can be written as $a_1 u_1 + \cdots + a_m u_m$. Since $S \in \mathcal{L}(U, W)$, by Definition 3.2 we have
> $$Su = a_1 Su_1 + a_2 S u_2 + \cdots + a_m S u_m.$$
> Since $T \in \mathcal{L}(V, W)$, we have
> \begin{align}
>     Tu &= T(a_1 u_1 + \cdots + a_m u_m) \\
>     &= a_1 T u_1 + a_2 T u_2 + \cdots a_m T u_m \\
>     &= a_1 S u_1 + a_2 S u_2 + \cdots a_m S u_m \\
>     &= Su.
> \end{align}
> Therefore we have $Tu = Su$ for all $u \in U$, so we have proved that every linear map on a subspace of $V$ can be extended to a linear map on $V$.

The solution proves that $Tu = Su$ for all $u \in U$, but I do not see how that is sufficient to show that $T$ is linear — what about those elements in $V$ that are *not* in $U$?

Suppose $U'$ is the complementary subspace to $U$ (that is, $U \oplus U' = V$). I believe any element in $U'$ can be expressed as a linear combination of $v_1, \ldots, v_n$. Now take $a, b \in V$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{F}$. To prove $T$ is linear, I believe we need to show that
$$ T(\lambda a + b) = \lambda T(a) + T(b) $$
holds, even if (among other combinations) $a \in U$ and $b \in U'$. How (if at all) does the Stanford proof address this? It seems to me that they only consider the case where both $a$ and $b$ are in $U$.

Comment: "Using Proposition 3.5, we know there exists a unique **linear** map $T\in \mathcal{L}(V,W)\dots$". The author is using some prior result which already guarantees that this map $T$ will be linear. Any doubts about the linearity, I guess, are supposed to be addressed by reviewing the Proposition being referenced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This point is addressed "under the hood" in the statement

> Using Proposition 3.5, we know that there exists a unique linear map $T \in \mathcal{L}(V, W)$ such that
> \begin{align} 
>     Tu_i = Su_i \quad &\text{for all} \quad i \in \{1, 2, \ldots, m\} \\
>     Tv_j = 0 \quad &\text{for all} \quad j \in \{ 1, 2, \ldots, n \} .
> \end{align}

It is specified that $T$ is a *linear* map, so we already know that $T$ is linear.

As for what $T$ does to elements not in $U$: a vector $v \notin U$ can be expressed as
$$
v = a_1 u_1 + \cdots + a_m u_m + b_1 v_1 + \cdots + b_n v_n,
$$
and the fact that $v \notin U$ tells us that one of the coefficients $b_j$ is non-zero. We find that
$$
T(v) = a_1 T(u_1) + \cdots + a_m T(u_m) + b_1 T(v_1) + \cdots + b_n T(v_n)
\\ = a_1 T(u_1) + \cdots + a_m T(u_m).
$$
Note that they could have equivalently made a proof using a complementary subspace. The complementary subspace corresponding to the map constructed in the proof is $U' = \operatorname{span}\{v_1,\dots,v_m\}$, and $T$ was defined so that $T|_{U'} = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different way of defining the same map, where the linearity might be more apparent. Let $P: V \rightarrow U$ be orthogonal projection onto $U$. This is a linear map. Then for any $v \in V$, define the desired extension $\tilde{T}: V \rightarrow W$ as $\tilde{T}(v) := T(P(v))$. This extension will clearly be linear, and it will be the same as the given one if the basis $u_1, ..., u_m$ is completed with vectors $v_1, ..., v_n$ which are all orthogonal to $U$. I'm not familiar with the textbook or the course, though, so I don't know if you have gotten up to inner products and projection maps yet.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

there is a subspace $U_0$ of $V$ such that $V= U \oplus U_0.$ Then define $T:V \to W$ as follows:

if $v \in V$, there are uniquely determined $u \in U$ and $u_0 \in U_0$ such that $v=u+u_0.$ Now put

$$Tv:= Su.$$

It is easy to see that $T$ is linear and that $Tu=Su$ for all $u \in U.$